# Pointer to the head of the tree

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have this class (I know, horrible.. I am just starting to work with classes in c++ and the pointers kind of getting hard for me so.. :) ):

```
class Tree{
private:
    Tree* Left;
    Tree* Right;
    int info;
    Tree* GetTree(int num){
        return new Tree(num);
    }
public:
    Tree() :info(0) ,Left(nullptr), Right(nullptr) {};
    Tree(int num) : info(num), Left(nullptr) , Right(nullptr){};
    Tree(int num,Tree* L,Tree* R) : info(num), Left(L), Right(R) {};
    void SetLeft(Tree* L){Left = L;};
    void SetRight(Tree* R){Right = R;};
    void SetLeft(Tree L){Left = &L;};
    void SetRight(Tree R){Right = &R;};
    void SetLeft(int num){Left = GetTree(num);};
    void SetRight(int num){Right = GetTree(num);};
    void SetInfo(int num){info = num;};
    Tree GetLeft(){return (Left==nullptr) ? Tree() : *Left;};
    Tree GetRight(){return (Right==nullptr) ? Tree() : *Right;};
    Tree* GetLeft(bool ptr){return Left;};
    Tree* GetRight(bool ptr){return Right;};
    int GetInfo(){return info;};
};
```

(Basically this class create a tree that have 2 leaves(2 more trees), Left and Right, and each of them have more 2 leaves and so on..)
so i did this:

```
Tree temp(5);
Tree* tem = &temp;
temp.SetInfo(10);
temp.SetLeft(5);
temp = temp.GetLeft();
cout << tem->GetInfo();
```

hoping that *tem* will point to the head of the tree, but it just follow the *temp*..
is there a way to do this easily?

can can you guys help me out with the class? 
I am having a hard time combining pointers and classes S:

thanks!

Comment: tem is a pointer to temp, so when you change temp, tem also will point to new values.

Comment: so what should i do to make tem point to the head of the tree of temp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hoping that tem will point to the head of the tree, but it just follow the temp

Of course, it will point to the `temp`, because here:

```
Tree* tem = &temp;
```

You assign it with address of `temp`. Then

```
temp = temp.GetLeft();
```

You change the `temp` with it's left children. But `tem` is still pointing to the `temp`, that's why you got this result.

I don't see any reason for changing `temp` with its left child. I can suggest you declare a new variable, that will hold a left child...

## But firstly:

You have to rewrite your class, it has a lot of mistakes. At least - memory leaks. If you have allocated(by yourself) memory, you have to manually release it.

Instead of it, use smart pointers and don't use constructor with `Tree*` as arguments. It may be dangerous.

## So:

It's great to learn all at once. **But this does not work**.

- Learn, how to use pointers(separately from using classes)
- Learn, how to use classes(separately from using pointers)
- Learn pointers and classes together

Comment: Yeah I saw i had a mistake there.. 
im trying to create a tree so i have to move temp to left and right, the example i gave above is a short version of what im trying to do.
is there a way to create a pointer to the top of the tree without making it follow along with the temp?
About the class, I will fix that later, i did that because i had no idea how to fix some problems, i will deal with that later on, thanks!

Comment: By the way i actually did learn how to use them separately, using them together?.. yeah.. not my strong side (+ i cant find a good tutorial about it and my book does not teach that..)

Comment: As I already told, you can declare a new `Tree` object, and assign it with left child. Then, you can use it separately.

Comment: I cant actually do that S:
Is there a way to use only one Tree object to do this? :\

(When i say i cant, its because im using recursive function and i need only one tree object to deal with (it will be a pain to use both left and right in this function))

Comment: So, you want to declare an `Tree` object. Then, you want to add a left child into it. After it, you what to assign this object with its left child. In fact, after it, other(right) child will be destroyed(and information in the parent will be lost too). So, before doing that, you have to copy your tree to save right child. But you can't do this with one object.

Comment: @NaorHadar, Also, it's better to show, what are you trying to **solve**. Maybe, an easier solution exists.

Comment: Maximum path sum I - At Project Euler, Actually i rather to figure it out myself :)
Thanks Though :)

Comment: @NaorHadar, There is no reason for creating a class for this problem. This could be solved with a technique, similar to DP. [Code](http://pastebin.com/UAaCsEdA)